# Question about executing yum install with AWS CDK configured Proxy and Backend EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am setting up a proxy and backend server using the AWS CDK. The code snippet below configures AWS proxy and backend servers.

```js
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as iam from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';

export class Ec2CdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // Create new VPC with 2 Subnets
    const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'VPC', {
      natGateways: 0,
      subnetConfiguration: [
        {
          cidrMask: 24,
          name: 'asterisk',
          subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
        },
      ],
    });

    // Use Latest Amazon Linux Image - CPU Type ARM64
    const ami = new ec2.AmazonLinuxImage({
      generation: ec2.AmazonLinuxGeneration.AMAZON_LINUX_2,
      cpuType: ec2.AmazonLinuxCpuType.ARM_64
    });

    // Allow SSH (TCP Port 22) access from anywhere
    const securityGroupProxy = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'SecurityGroupProxy', {
      vpc,
      description: 'Allow incoming HTTP and ICMP from anywhere.',
      allowAllOutbound: true,
    });
    securityGroupProxy.addIngressRule(ec2.Peer.anyIpv4(), ec2.Port.allTraffic(), 'Allow all traffic');

    const securityGroupBackend = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'SecurityGroupBackend', {
      vpc,
      description: 'Allow incoming HTTP from the proxy.',
      allowAllOutbound: true,
    });
    securityGroupBackend.addIngressRule(securityGroupProxy, ec2.Port.tcp(80), 'Allow HTTP traffic from the proxy');

    const role = new iam.Role(this, 'ec2Role', {
      assumedBy: new iam.ServicePrincipal('ec2.amazonaws.com'),
    });
    role.addManagedPolicy(iam.ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName('AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore'));

    const backendUserData = ec2.UserData.forLinux();
    backendUserData.addCommands(
      '#!/bin/bash -ex',
      'trap \'/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e 1 --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource Backend --region ${AWS::Region}\' ERR',
      'yum -y install httpd',
      'systemctl start httpd',
      `echo '<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Hello AWS in Action!</title></head><body><p>Hello AWS in Action!</p></body></html>' > /var/www/html/index.html`,
      '/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e 0 --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource Backend --region ${AWS::Region}',
    );

    const backend = new ec2.Instance(this, 'Backend', {
      vpc,
      instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T4G, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO),
      machineImage: ami,
      securityGroup: securityGroupBackend,
      role,
      userData: backendUserData,
    });

    const proxyUserData = ec2.UserData.forLinux();
    proxyUserData.addCommands(
      '#!/bin/bash -ex',
      'trap \'/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e 1 --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource Proxy --region ${AWS::Region}\' ERR',
      'amazon-linux-extras install haproxy2',
      `cat <<"EOF" | tee /etc/haproxy2/haproxy2.cfg > /dev/null
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example configuration for a possible web application.  See the
# full configuration options online.
#
#   https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/configuration.txt
#
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy2
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy2.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy2/stats

    # utilize system-wide crypto-policies
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM
    ssl-default-server-ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# main frontend which proxies to the backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend main
    bind *:80
    default_backend             app

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# round robin balancing between the various backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend app
    balance     roundrobin
    http-response set-header X-Backend %s
    server  app1 ${backend.instancePrivateIp}:80 check
EOF`,
      'systemctl start haproxy2',
      '/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e 0 --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource Proxy --region ${AWS::Region}',
    );

    const proxy = new ec2.Instance(this, 'Proxy', {
      vpc,
      instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T4G, ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO),
      machineImage: ami,
      securityGroup: securityGroupProxy,
      role,
      userData: proxyUserData,
    });

    // 프록시 인스턴스가 백엔드 인스턴스에 종속되도록 설정
    proxy.node.addDependency(backend);

    // Create outputs for connecting
    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'ProxyPublicIpAddress', { value: proxy.instancePublicIp, description: 'Proxy public IP address' });
    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'BackendPublicIpAddress', { value: backend.instancePublicIp, description: 'Backend public IP address' });
  }
}
```

The proxy server is set up to receive all traffic, and the backend server is set to allow only traffic from the proxy server. In the security group settings for the backend server, it's configured to allow only HTTP traffic from the proxy server.

However, I have a question here. With these settings, would the backend server be able to successfully execute the yum install command? The yum install command typically requires downloading packages from an external repository, hence needs to communicate with the outside. I am doubtful since this communication seems to be restricted.

Could anyone help me understand this? Or is there something I am missing? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I tried to get an answer by searching the internet, but was unable to get a straight answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your VPC configuration, you only have public subnets. So your backend server is deployed to a public subnet. And it appears, from your output, that you are also assigning public IPs to al your instances. Additionally, the security group assigned to your backend server has the following setting: `allowAllOutbound: true`.

So your backend server:

1. Is in a public subnet (a subnet with a route to an Internet Gateway)
2. Has a public IP address (which is a requirement to directly make use of an Internet Gateway)
3. Has a security group that allows all outbound traffic

Given the above, and [the stateful nature of security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-group-rules.html), the backend server should be able to generate outbound network requests to anything on the Internet, and receive responses to those network requests.

So yes, the backend server should be able to perform `yum install` successfully.

Comment: I didn't know about the stateful for AWS security groups, thanks for the answer.